# absolute div visibility outside of div relative parent

Tags: html, css, css-position, parent

CSS:

```
ul#menu-ediloc li  
{  
float:left; 
padding-left:5px; 
position:relative; 
}

ul#menu-ediloc ul  
{
z-index:500; 
position:absolute; 
}
```

I have a drop menu like this, but when it goes down the sub menu is hidden where it touches the next `div` with is a slideshow and it's outside the relative parent.

I tryed to put `position:relative;` to body but although it fixes the visibility problem it than messes up my menu.

Any ideas?

```
<div id="header">
   <ul id="menu-ediloc">
      <li>
          <ul id="sub-menu">
               <li>
               </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div id="slider">
</div>
```

I tryed to put the slider in the header and put `relative` on header, but its same as on body it messes up my sub-menu.
The only way my sub-menu works if i put the `relative` on the `ul li` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following css

```
#header{
 position: relative;
 z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: I tryed like you said but it dosen't change anything.